# getting attributes in a product loop

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have looked at all the examples online for getting attributes from a product.  It seems relatively simple, but I just can't get any results.  I'm starting to think it is just not setup properly in the wp-admin.

The code I'm using:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'product_cat'    => $meal->slug,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $attribute_value = wc_get_product_terms( get_the_id(), 'pa_calories' );

    var_dump($attribute_value);

    echo '<div class="meal-products bottom col-md-6">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
endwhile;
```

I've tried other code snippets like `get_terms()` etc. but I keep getting empty strings or false. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My naive problem was because I was not noticing the attribute wasn't being saved when I clicked save attributes.  The reason it wasn't being saved was because I wasn't entering a value for the attrib.